# Using alternate regions in templates

Tags: menu, atk4

I'm trying to create a vertical Menu and after looking in the default template file I see that the standard is a horizontal one but there is also a region for a vertical menu (`MenuVertical`). What I can't figure out is how the heck I change the region used from `Menu` to `MenuVertical`. I've searched for hours in the documentation and looking through class references, but I can't figure it out.

I'm new to this framework and I guess this is VERY easy to do, but what isn't easy when you know how to do it eh? :)

**EDIT**: Just to be clear, this is a question about the Agile Toolkit Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's very easy. When you create an object, you specify template and a region as 4th argument:

```
$this->add('Menu',null,null,array('menu','VerticalMenu'));
```

If omitted object takes the value from the defaultTemplate method:

```
function defaultTemplate(){
    return array('menu','VerticalMenu');
}
```